# Python use string value as class / part of code

Tags: python, python-2.7

is it possible to use a value of a string directly inside of the code as a class etc? I don't know to exactly describe what I want to do with words, so the pseudo code version is probably the best way to understand what's the issue. Here is the example:

```
for node in itemdict.iterkeys():
    nodeinfo = itemdict.get(node)

    if nodeinfo[4] == "node": #create new Links based on original nodeclass
        #Example if nodeinfo[1] == "Dot"
        #link = nuke.nodes.Dot(hide_input=nodeinfo[3], label='to: ' + nodeinfo[2])
        link = nuke.nodes.XXX_value of nodeinfo[1] here_XX(hide_input=nodeinfo[3], label='to: ' + nodeinfo[2])
```

Comment: Take a look at [eval](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval)

Comment: Doesn't `getattr` do exactly what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `getattr` builtin function to get attributes from objects by name:

```
for node in itemdict.iterkeys():
    nodeinfo = itemdict.get(node)

    if nodeinfo[4] == "node": #create new Links based on original nodeclass
        # Get the attribute named <the value of nodeinfo[1]> from nuke.nodes
        cls = getattr(nuke.nodes, nodeinfo[1])
        link = cls(hide_input=nodeinfo[3], label='to: ' + nodeinfo[2])
```

If the object does not have an attribute wit the name that you passed to `getattr`, an `AttributeError` will be raised.  You can either handle this error in your code or pass a third argument to `getattr`, which `getattr` will return instead raising `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a class by name, you can use the built-in function [`globals`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals) to obtain it.

For example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 1

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.number = 2

for name in 'A', 'B':
    print(globals()[name]().number)
```

This outputs:

```
1
2
```